# $K(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}^N} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}$, then $D_x^aD_t^k K(x-y,t)\le C\exp(-c|y|^2)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Let $$K(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}^N} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}},
>  t>0, x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
>
> Show that if $u_0\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ then $$u(x,t) =
>  \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u_0(y)K(x-y,t)dy$$ is infinitely differentiable in
>   $\mathbb{R}^N\times ]0,\infty[$.
>
> Suggestion: fix $0<a<b$ and $R>0$ and verify that given
>   $a\in\mathbb{Z}_+^N, k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, there exists constants $C>0,
>  c>0, p>0$ such that $$D_x^aD_t^k K(x-y,t)\le C\exp(-c|y|^2),
>  x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N, |x|\le R, |y|\le p, t\in [a,b]$$

I've used Leibniz product differentiation rule and ended up with

$$D_t^k K = \sum_i^k{k\choose i}\prod_{j=1}^{k-i}\left(\frac{-N}{2}-j\right)(4\pi t)^{-\frac{N}{2}-j}4^j\pi^i \frac{(-|x|)^{2i}}{4i}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}$$

which is already pretty absurd and looks like won't help. I, however, don't see another way of taking thederivative. I know that that product can be converted into a combinatorial but only for even $N$. I still have to take $D_x^a$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to keep track of the coefficients, only that you have some control:
$$
D^k_t(K(x,t))=p_k(x,t^{-1}) K(x,t)
$$
where $p_k$ is a polynomial of degree $4k$.  Similarly, take care of the $D_x^\alpha$
$$
D^\alpha_x(D^k_t(K(x-t)) = Q_{k,\alpha}(x,t^{-1}) K(x,t)
$$
with $Q_{k,\alpha}$ a polynomial of degree $4k+2\lvert\alpha\rvert$.

For polynomial $Q_{k,\alpha}$, you can bound
\begin{align}
\lvert Q_{k,\alpha}(x-y,t)\rvert&\leq \overbrace{(\#\text{monomials})}^{=C(k,\alpha,N)}\times\\
&\quad\times\underbrace{(\max\lvert\text{coefficients}\rvert)}_{\leq C(k,\alpha,N)}\times
(\sup\text{bound on monomial})
\end{align}
where we use the obvious notation $C(\dots)$ for a universal constant depending only on the those variables listed.  Now just bound away each monomial, giving
\begin{align}
\lvert(x-y)^\beta t^{-j}\rvert&\leq C(R,\lvert\beta\rvert)(1+\lvert y\rvert^2)^{d/2}\cdot\max(1,a^{-j})\\
&\leq C(R,d,a)(1+\lvert y\rvert^2)^{d/2}
\end{align}
for every degree bound $d$, every $\lvert x\rvert\leq R$, every $y\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and every $t\in[a,b]$.  Thus we bound
$$
(1+\lvert y\rvert^2)^{d/2}\lvert K(x-y,t)\rvert\leq C(d,R,a,N,\varepsilon)\exp(-(1/(4b)-\varepsilon)\lvert y\rvert^2)
$$
for all $\lvert x\rvert\leq R$, $t\in[a,b]$ and $\varepsilon>0$.  Note we weaken the coefficient of $\lvert y\rvert^2$ in the exponential to help get the bound in front for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the degree of the polynomials? I cannot see why the degrees are like that

Comment: I did the first derivative and I can only find $t$ to have degree 2 and $x$ to have degree 2

Comment: $D_t$ if act outside of $\exp$ it merely increases $t^{-1}$-degree by 1; if acts on the exponential, it brings a $\lvert x\rvert^2/t^2$, so increases the total degree by 4.  Similarly, $D_{x_i}$ on exponential brings a $x_i/t$, so increases total degree by $2$.

Comment: The degree of the $x$ derivative gave me only $|\alpha|$

Comment: plus the degree os the t terms which are $2k$ for me

Comment: Try it on $K$ for $N=1$, you will see: $D_x K=-\frac12 xt^{-1} K$ so there are $2\lvert\alpha\rvert$.  Similarly $D_tK=(-\frac12 t^{-1} + x^2t^{-2}/4) K$ so there are $4k$.

Comment: I agree with your comment, but in the product rule I sum these polynomials, not multiply, so the degree should be the maximum of them, not the product

Comment: I tried your derivative, but instead of deriving for $x$, I did for $x_j$ and did the composition of many of these derivatives. The $t$ terms multiply themselves lots of times

Comment: For me, in your $D_t K$, the maximum degree is 2, so it should be $2.1$ so $2k$

Comment: I'm considering total degree, not bidegree.

Comment: What is $C(R)$? At first it looks like the function $C$ applied to $R$, but $C$ is a two variable function

Comment: It is a common convention.  $C(\text{blah})$ is a constant depending only on the variables blah, to let us concentrate on what we really ought to bound..